# Changing the order of items in a CSS grid from left-right to top-down

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm building a list of tags in a system, and those tags should be displayed in a CSS grid with three columns. So, something like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Alfa</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Delta</li>
    <li>Echo</li>
    <li>Foxtrot</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

When viewing this in a browser, the items are ordered like this:

```
Alfa  Bravo Charlie
Delta Echo  Foxtrot
```

However, i would like them to be ordered like this:

```
Alfa  Charlie Echo
Bravo Delta   Foxtrot
```

So, basically ordered from top to bottom instead of left-right.

Is there any way to do this in a simple way? I already experimented a bit with `:nth-child` selectors and `grid-column`, but that doesn't really do what i want. I could probably solve this with Javascript, but i like to know if there's a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Couldn't you do it in css? Rearrange the tag positions, copy and paste the names into their designated orders.

Comment: @AJAnde You mean to change the order of the list in the HTML? That could work, but i want this to be responsive and be represented as a single column list on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use columns instead of grid columns for this

```css
ul{
  columns: 3
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Alfa</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Delta</li>
    <li>Echo</li>
    <li>Foxtrot</li>
</ul>
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that there is a `columns` property for `ul`. Nice to know. :-)

Comment: @Jadawin not just for ul, this will work for many other elements as well. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).

Comment: My li consist of `li > div > input + label`, the label breaks into 2 parts, part 1 at the bottom of the table, part 2 at the top of the table, can this be prevent?

Answer (score -1):

I did only a short research on this.

It seems like `grid-auto-flow: column` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-flow.php) does what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Instead of laying out the items in a column, it just puts all the elements in line after each other. [See codepen example here](https://codepen.io/hay/pen/XWyvVQv).

Comment: @Husky It's strange. As soon as I start editing your codepen the layout of the list switches to the correct form. When I finished editing the list switches back to the wrong one-line-layout. This seem to be a codepen glitch. Have you had a look at w3schools "Try it yourself" page linked from the page I linked in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
    <ul style="display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;">
    <li>Alfa</li>
    <li style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1;">Bravo</li>
    <li style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;">Charlie</li>
    <li style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 2;">Delta</li>
    <li style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 3;">Echo</li>
    <li style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 3;">Foxtrot</li>
    </ul>
```

if you want to have a separate CSS page give each li a specific class name like li1, li2, li3 and so on, and then set their CSS property to them as I have done above.

for example:

```
li2{
grid-row:2;
grid-column:1
}
```

with grid-row and grid-column you can order your items in any direction you want.

Comment: This would work, but it doesn't scale for more than a couple of items. I have a couple of pages that have more than a thousand items.

Comment: I had another solution but it seems you have found your answer :D @Husky